# Is there a way to check if JTAG debugging is still supported in Raspberry Pi OS?

Tags: raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have been trying to get JTAG debugging working on several Raspberry Pi's for the better part of three days. No matter what I try, I cannot get the TDO pin to return anything. It just stays floating. I am beginning to think that JTAG debugging is just not supported any more and the documentation never got updated. I learned halfway through this effort that the `enable_jtag_gpio` option in `config.txt` is now considered legacy and ignored by Bookworm, but I can't get it to work in Bullseye or even Buster. All the info online regarding JTAG debugging on the Pi is between 2 - 8 years old, which is plenty of time for this feature to have gotten disabled by accident.

**What I have tried**

- Two different debuggers (LPC-Link2 and an FT232 based one). The LPC link I tried with both the CMSIS-DAP firmware and the JLink firmware. I've confirmed both debuggers do indeed work, they can attach and debug other chips just fine.
- Three different Raspberry Pi's. Two 3B's and one 4B.
- Connecting the debugger JTAG pins to the ALT4 and ALT5 JTAG pins on both Pi variants https://pinout.xyz/pinout/jtag
- Bookworm, Bullseye, and Buster variants of Raspberry Pi OS. Buster did not work at all on the Pi4, that was tested on the Pi 3's. Tried 32 and 64 bit variants of Bookworm and Buster on the 4B. Bullseye was 32 bit only.
- Added the following to `/boot/config.txt`

```
# Disable pull downs
gpio=22-27=np

# Enable jtag pins (i.e. GPIO22-GPIO27)
enable_jtag_gpio=1
```

also tried a different pull-up configuration, as recommended by probe.rs

```
# Disable pull downs
gpio=27=pu

# Enable JTAG
enable_jtag_gpio=1
```

I've confirmed that these options are actually getting set by running `vcgencmd get_config enable_jtag_gpio`

- Two different debugging frameworks, OpenOCD (latest mainline with BCM2711 support, built from source) and probe.rs. Neither could wiggle TDO.
- I've checked the connections between the Pi and my debuggers so many times that I have now memorized all the JTAG GPIOs.

I've completely hit a wall and I am not sure what else to check. I get no feedback from the hardware at all, just no response over TDO so I have no errors to chase. Is there any other way to check that JTAG is still enabled, or some kind of log that will tell me if anything is wrong with my setup?

Comment: *"Bookworm, Bullseye, and Buster variants of Raspberry Pi OS. Buster did not work at all on the Pi4, that was tested on the Pi 3's. Tried 32 and 64 bit variants of Bookworm and Buster on the 4B. Bullseye was 32 bit only."*  Do you mean for JTAG debugging or in general?  If the latter,  this is a very peculiar problem that you need to diagnose first  before you use the 4B for anything, as the great majority of users have not had that problem...

Comment: ...I've used Buster and Bullseye on a Pi 4, and if you look around here and elsewhere you'll notice there are not tons of people complaining about this despite the fact that there have been hundreds of thousands of them made, if not millions, and most of those would have been running Rpi OS Buster or Bullseye at some point.  I mention this because it raises the possibility that your problems are more fundamental than JTAG debugging, hence it may be that you are not doing anything wrong there.